# Terraform aws_route53_zone destroyed when creating record

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform

I created a hosted zone via terraform on a separate project. Now, I want to reuse that same hosted zone in a new project using a different backend and leave the hosted zone managed by the other project.

So, I have used the following code for the new project to reuse the existing hosted zone:

```
data "aws_route53_zone" "selected" {
  name         = "somealreadyexistingzone.com"
  private_zone = false
}

resource "aws_route53_record" "record1" {
  zone_id = data.aws_route53_zone.selected.zone_id
  name    = "anewsubdomain"
  type    = "A"
  ttl     = "300"
  records = ["8.8.8.8"]
}
```

As I terraform plan, I see that the plan is to create the A record with the correct zone id et al, but to destroy the zone *# (because aws_route53_zone.domain is not in configuration)*

What am I doing wrong?

Edit: So it seems this only happens on terraform v1.2.2 (latest to date) and not on earlier versions (confirmed on terraform v1.2.1 and v1.2.0). The terraform code is correct for that effect.

Edit2: Can't reproduce anymore on terraform v1.2.2. I didn't register on my earlier testing the provider version, but the current one on which I can't reproduce is provider registry.terraform.io/hashicorp/aws v4.17.1

Comment: Is the zone in the same region? Where is the state file for that zone?

Comment: same region. I just discovered that it only happens on terraform 1.2.2. Not happening on 1.2.0

Comment: The plan wouldn't be trying to delete something that isn't in the state. There has to be more happening than what is reflected in your question. Can you provide the `plan` output?

Comment: It sounds like you are using the same state storage location for both of your configurations, and so the second configuration (which doesn't declare `aws_route53_zone.domain`) is trying to respond to the state created by the first configuration (which does). You need to make sure that all of your configurations have distinct state storage locations, so that they will not try to modify each other's infrastructure objects.

Comment: I just confirmed and the tfstate file doesn't have the zone as managed. It has the records as managed and the zone as data. This seems to be de facto a 1.2.2 bug. A pretty breaking one.

Comment: Well, I can't reproduce anymore as everything is working fine now without me changing the terraform files. It was probably a bug not on terraform but on the provider version which I didn't register at the time. But I can't replicate the issue on terraform v1.2.2 with provider registry.terraform.io/hashicorp/aws v4.17.1

Comment: I might have messed up with the backend config and shared the state file as it has been mentioned. When I was having the issue the v4.17.1 aws provider was being used too. Thanks for your help guys and apologies for the no issue.